# Is unordered_map safe for concurrent reading only?

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I know STL containers are not thread safe, but I think they should be safe for concurrent reading only. A program I am working on shows unexpected little variations when I switched it from monothread to multithreads. Rewieving my code and possible bugs with no success, I am starting questioning my beliefs.

Is `unordered_map` safe for concurrent reading only ?
The keys existence is tested, if it exist, the `[]` operator is used for reading the value and different threads might read at the same key at the same time.

Comment: Yes, concurrent reading from unmodified container is safe.

Comment: Thank you and Baum mit Augen, I have my answer. I upvoted the post from Baum mit Augen. This thread can be closed, it is a duplicate.

Comment: Note that `unordered_map::find` returns an iterator to the found element so you can test for a key's existence and read the value in one go. No need for an extra lookup with `operator[]`

Comment: Yes, I will use this way for reading the values. Thx.